# htaccess redirect - use subfolders as parameters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I've been working out an htaccess redirect directive for (example) an online shop.

Products are displayed on product.php, with an ID parameter passed in.

What I'm aiming for is to have

`products/someValue/someID`

map to

`product.php?param1=someValue&param2=someID`

Here's where I'm at so far. This mostly works, but a couple of things are not quite what I want. I need it to basically separate everything after `products/` by forward slashes and use each of those as a parameter, regardless of how many or few. also, a trailing slash is optional - my rule throws a 404 if it's not included. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*)/.*$ /product.php?param1=$1&param2=$2
```

Comment: What does the url look like that it gets redirected to now?

Comment: if I access `products/1/2/`, it resolves to `product.php?param1=1&param2=2`. This is great, but if I change it to `products/1/2/3/`, it goes to `product.php?param1=1/2&param2=3`. Can't figure out why, regex isn't something I'm good at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current regex is greedy. Quantifiers are greedy by default. Adding a `?` makes them ungreedy. Or you can change your regex to match anything except `/` Either of these should work:

```
RewriteRule ^products/(.*?)/(.*?)(/.*)?$ /product.php?param1=$1&param2=$2
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/.*)?$ /product.php?param1=$1&param2=$2
```

[Read up on greediness in regexes to understand this better.](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.regex/greedy.html)

Comment: thanks for this, did the trick perfectly! I knew I was close. The link is great too, finally making sense :) Bot yours and @JonLin's answers do the trick, thanks to you both

Comment: @jammypeach - You're welcome. :) By the way, by replacing `/.*` with `(/.*)?` at the end of the regex, it allows it so your url doesn't need a trailing `/`.

Comment: yeah I saw that, have been playing round with it by implementing one change at a time to mine. Wish I had a better knowledge of regex, time to get my learning hat on again :)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the regex to non-greedy:

```
RewriteRule ^products/(.*?)/(.*?)/.*$ /product.php?param1=$1&param2=$2
```

or:

```
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/.*$ /product.php?param1=$1&param2=$2
```